# Not getting any results from AWS RDS when calling from node lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need help. I've been spinning my wheels reading stackechange all day and I've still not been able to crack this.

I've got a serverless AWS RDS DB up and running. I know it's there as I've connected to it through a tunning on an EC2 instance from my desktop (that's when I set up all the tables and data I want).

I'm now trying to connect to it and run stuff using a lambda written in node (that I'm learning).

The code I've got is this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

var mysql = require('mysql');
console.log('Making connection');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com",
  user: "xxxxx",
  password: "xxxxxx",
  database: "xxxxxx"
});

console.log('About to query');
con.query('SELECT * FROM players', function(error, results, fields) {
  console.log('Query has run');
  console.log('Row Details:', JSON.stringify(results));
  context.succeed(JSON.stringify(results));
});

};
```

But for the life of me I can't see a result coming back. I get things like this in the cloudwatch logs:

```
START RequestId: a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581 Version: $LATEST
2018-11-22T16:06:55.667Z    a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581    Making connection
2018-11-22T16:06:56.356Z    a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581    About to query
END RequestId: a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581
REPORT RequestId: a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581  Duration: 769.66 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB
START RequestId: be7f1fbd-ee70-11e8-981b-c1b991028291 Version: $LATEST
2018-11-22T16:07:43.497Z    a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581    Query has run
2018-11-22T16:07:43.515Z    a1e383cc-ee70-11e8-aac6-51ba776a3581    Row Details: undefined
2018-11-22T16:07:43.535Z    be7f1fbd-ee70-11e8-981b-c1b991028291    Making connection
2018-11-22T16:07:43.535Z    be7f1fbd-ee70-11e8-981b-c1b991028291    About to query
END RequestId: be7f1fbd-ee70-11e8-981b-c1b991028291
```

I think a call is being made to the DB as I'm not seeing errors.

I'm calling it from the test function on the AWS Lambda console and I'm assuming I should see some JSON come back as the body of the call. However all I get is "null"

I'm guessing I'm not seeing results because of the async nature of the call. But everything I've been reading tells me the code should be working and should be waiting for the call to come back, or at least it should within the lifetime of this call.

I'm completely stuck. If anyone can give me a hint, or point me at a web page that explains how to get it work, I'd be very VERY appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to a mix between [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and non-async await code. The smallest change you can make to fix this is to remove the async keyword before the handler function's signature, like so:

`exports.handler = (event, context) => {`

If you'd still like to use async functions, you'll have to update the mysql query code using the workaround stated here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1755#issuecomment-345459882

Comment: Thanks. Making that small change has meant the call now works. I guess I have further to go with understanding Async-await and database calls!